# A sudden string of downvotes

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

All of a sudden, I've lost nearly 56 points, if not more, what can be the explanation for this? Or is this a troll?

Is this due to an account deletion?
[image]

Comment: 2 is typically the rep for a successful edit.  If an account was deleted and you've edited a lot of that accounts posts, that might explain it

Comment: @postmortes, I've only edited around two questions , or so.

Comment: Moreover, these are my own questions

Comment: I visited my profile, and this seems to have happened yesterday too(it was revered), but it has happened again(today,with the -38 reputation), do I flag one of my posts, or wait for some time?

Comment: Looks like blatant serial downvoting. It should be reversed, and if not flag your posts and the moderators can investigate.

Comment: By the way if an account was deleted it would say 'user removed', and those do happen occasionally.

Comment: I would expect you'll see a reversal after 3:00 UTC  Only then, if not, then you can address mods in their chatroom, or flag one of the downvoted post with a convenient link to your reputation, for moderator attention.  But please refrain from posting to meta in such cases, as there is nothing meta users can do.

Comment: Your title is redundant: *A **sudden** string of downvotes all of a **sudden***.  Did you do that for dramatic effect?

Comment: no, not really. that's the only title that felt natural to me  @amWhy. If you want, I'll change it

Comment: @amWhy, understood, I won't make such posts in the future

Comment: @bobeyt6, I see. Thanks!

Comment: This was blatant serial voting. The timing data on the votes leaves no doubt. Looks like the removal of a user fixed things, so the system works as intended. The moderators are not authorized to give any more information. Move on, hopefully happily.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, yes. Thank you!